# Why does "Out of Memory" error occur in this loop in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

Why does this code snippet give an "Out of Memory" error in Excel 2010.

```
Sub naming()
Dim cell As Range
Dim cells As Range
Set cells = Range("C1:E1")
For Each cell In cells
Worksheets("Sheet1").cells.Name = Worksheets("Sheet1").cells.Value
Next cell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

`Cells` already has a predefined meaning as a property of a range or worksheet object. `Worksheets("Sheet1").cells.Value` would be a giant array containing the values of all cells in a worksheet, which is much too large to hold in memory. Don't use `cells` as the name of a variable. It is asking for trouble.

Something like this works:

```
Sub naming()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim mycells As Range
    Set mycells = Range("C1:E1")
    For Each cell In mycells
        cell.Name = cell.Value
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Good explanation, never thought of that.

Comment: This is my actual Intention. I get an "Application-defined or Object-defined" error in this on "cell.Name = cell.Value" Sub naming()
Dim cell As Range
Dim MyCells As Range
Set MyCells = Workbooks("Book3.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C1:E1").Range(selection, selection.End(xlDown))
For Each cell In MyCells
cell.Name = cell.Value
Next cell
End Sub

Comment: @VarunKhanna Not all names are valid names. Can you determine what the problem name or names are? If the problem is one of embedded spaces, perhaps you can replace the spaces by underscores. Since Excel can object when you try to set a name, it might be a good idea to write an error-handler for that code.